# iptables equivalent command for mac os x

Tags: macos, tcp, iptables, scapy

I'm trying to write a Scapy program to initiate a TCP handshake. But the kernel is sending out RSTs when I get a SYNACK. To disable those RSTs on linux, https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/how-to-build-a-tcp-connection-in-scapy.html suggests using the following iptables command,

**iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP**

What is the equivalent command for mac OS X which uses pfctl?

Comment: This questions was answered here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/102416/iptables-equivalent-for-mac-os-x